# Flex TextField won't accept "ü" and other "German" characters

Tags: apache-flex, unicode

I'm having problems with Flex (3.5) auto converting "ü" into a "u".  As soon as I paste the character in, it transforms.

Is there something I need to turn on to enable these other character sets?  I thought Flex supported UTF-8?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Default setup on 3.3 which I use currently for german/english applciation doesn't behave like that. I made new dummy project and tried all text editable fields. Check Project Properties > Resource > Text file encoding and Flex compiler > Additional compiler arguments. If you didn't change anything there, than it's component you use. 
EDIT: OR, maybe it's font, if you use custom font...

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, german characters, but this problem was solved from ma PHP side developers, they did something, flex doesn't have n e problem in representing these special characters, so i was doin everything  fine from ma side

Answer (score 0):

What font are you using ? are you sure that the font is supporting those chars ? else you will get u or ? instead of ü.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too simple a question, but what language(s) do you have set in the flex-config.xml file? There are a couple of places that this can be set, including the font table suggested by Adrian.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Flash Text Laylout Framework as it supports the full character set.  This means use Flex 4 and either `<s:TextInput or s:TextArea` or any other of the spark components that use the TLF.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your default compiler args, the source file details and the html file your swf is embedded into, to make sure they use utf-8. also check the font type you are using, to see if the required characters are part of that set.